# Building website for Windows mobile 6.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, web, windows-mobile

I am making a website for windows mobile phones 6.1 and trying to figure out which browser to use. I have ran into a pattern that some functions that run on 1 browser don't work on another. So far I have tried

- `IE 6` - relatively better but bad alignment and page is zoomed in when opens
- `Opera Mobile 10` - Javascript keypress does not work, Although good alignment and screen resolution settings
- `Mozilla Fennec` - Best one so far but is really really slow.

Any ideas if I update IE/OS on these phones to solve this, I am trying to avoid buying new licenses?

Comment: netscape 2. its the same level of advancement and quality.

Comment: Mind if I ask why you are developing for WM 6.1? Very interested.

Comment: It's very hard to say anything without knowing anything about the website in question. Yes, newer versions of browsers are likely to behave differently. That's about as specific as anyone can say with this information.

Comment: @Juhana I am only prototyping right now to see even if I can make a descent website for WM6 and the website only contains couple of `bootstrap.js` controls sprinkled with some JavaScript and jquery

Comment: If your actual target isn't 6.1, then you shouldn't be evaluating on it.  Test on the actual hardware you intend to target, as the browsers between version of WinMo are significantly different (but keep in mind that none are very good).

Comment: @ctacke I think title of question makes it very clear what my target is :)

Comment: My point is that there are no 6.1 devices still being made today, so it's a bit of a surprise one would target it with new development, and your comment to @Juhana indicated this was a prototype.  Didn't know if you were prototyping with hardware you have, with a future deployment to newer devices.

Comment: @ctacke I am testing on the actual hardware

Answer (score 0):

Developing web sites for Desktop or Mobile is always a challenge with all the different browsers.

If you intend to use a batch of one mobile device model, you can define which browser has to be used. If you are not in that position, you have to work against different browsers.

On windows mobile 6.1 the only standard you can rely on is the built-in IE6 mobile browser.

If you can define a 3rd party browser, you may have a look at ZetaKey (based on WebKit).